# mRpostman - Search Email Since Specific Date Time

Tags: r, email, imap

Is there a way to read mail messages in R that were received since a specific date/time. I am using mRpostman package with the below code to filter by date but cannot seem to filter on a specific date/time.

```
con <- configure_imap(url="imaps://outlook.office365.com",
                           username="username",
                           password="password"
)

con$search_since(date_char = "28-Feb-2021")
```

Comment: The IMAP search language does not have anything more precise then a date/day in an unspecified time zone.  Time is not supported.  If you just want messages since the last time you checked, store the highest UID you have processed, and then fetch new UIDs higher then that.

Comment: Got it, thank you Max!